# Work with Array of Intent and copy one Intent to another Intent

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity

I am having a Listview and two buttons in my Activity,

when ADD button clicked it will call some other activity for result, that activity return a intent with data, each time diff data in the intent received, and the title only added to the listview,

when SAVE button clicked, all the intent data would be saved in database,

So I need to create intent array ie

> Inten[] intArray = new Intent[100];

and I need to copy the returned Intent each time **onActivityResult(Intent data)** to the Intent array as

> intArray[i] = data;

How can I achieve this, If I can do this I can solve a big problem in my Project....

Following is the code I tried.... **Intent[] intentArray = new Intent[100]; declared as this class variable**

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        switch(reqCode)
        {
            case 1:
                trigName = data.getStringExtra("TriggerName");
                subName = data.getStringExtra("SubName");

                intentArray[i] = data; i++;

                temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
                temp.put("Name", trigName);
                temp.put("Sub", subName);
                list.add(temp);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing as you didnt state what the issue you are having with the code supplied is... but

remove the call to `super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);`

or if you need to call it; call it at the end after you have processed the information required.

Comment: sorry @sorceri, my issue was I can't use array of intents as intent[], and intent[i], the error coming is "Failure delivering result",
My Ques: Can I use Array of Intents, and with extras..
If yes then please tell me how...